# In Java or Scala, how to define conditional control flow based on whether type bound is satisfied?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-bounds

In scala, I have a class definition:

```
class A[T >: Null]{}
```

And a function that optionally creates an instance:

```
def use[T](): Option[A[T]]
```

now I want to define it such that:

- it returns None if condition `T >: Null` is not satisfied
- it returns Some[A[T]] if it is satisfied.

How to write function `use` in this case?

Comment: Everything, except for primitives types, is a supertype of `Null`. It is not clear to me what exactly did you wanted to do here but have you tried a **typeclass**? or Maybe just a **generalized type constraint**.

Comment: This is an attempt to use UserDefinedType in Apache Spark, when RowEncoder API is not ready. Would you mind giving a short example?

Comment: It is hard to provide an example without an use case, could you please explain a bit more what exactly do you want to achieve? How does `use[T]` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is approach with a type class

```
def use[T]()(implicit sel: Selector[T]): sel.Out = sel.x

trait Selector[T] {
  type Out
  val x: Out
}

trait LowPrioritySelector {
  implicit def default[T]: Selector[T] { type Out = None.type } = new Selector[T] {
    override type Out = None.type
    override val x: Out = None
  }
}

object Selector extends LowPrioritySelector {
  implicit def superTypeOfNull[T >: Null]: Selector[T] { type Out = Some[A[T]] } = new Selector[T] {
    override type Out = Some[A[T]]
    override val x: Out = Some(new A[T])
  }
}

use[String]() // Some(App$A@34340fab)   
use[Int]() // None
```